# R lookup interpolate between values or closest match

Tags: r, interpolation, lookup

I have a dataset of reservoir volumes (9 columns for 9 reservoirs) and I want to use a lookup (or similar functions) in R to convert the volumes to levels using a rating table (my rating table has got two columns, volumes and levels). If I use lookup, it does not interlope between rating table values and generates series of N/A.
Note: the number of rows in rating table is different with the number of rows in the dataset.
My code is similar to this
storagelevel1 <- lookup(storagevolume[,1],storagerating)
This code lookup the level from storagerating (two columns, volumes and levels) using the volumes from storagevolume but it does not interpolate in the storageraitng.

How can I do this to interpolate or at least find the closest match in the lookup table?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide code with data and rating table. See [MCVE] for the hep page that you apparently have not yet read. You should also provide the code that you are referring to when you write: "If I use lookup, ...", since there is no "lookup" function in `base` or recommended packages of R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As 42 commented, very difficult to provide you with help if we don't know what you are working with. That said, does this code give you any insight?

```
storagerating <- data.frame(volumes = c(10, 100, 1000, 10000), 
                            levels = c("A","B","C","D"))
#  volumes levels
#1      10      A
#2     100      B
#3    1000      C
#4   10000      D

z <- 888 # a random volume
storagerating$levels[which.min(abs(z - storagerating$volumes))] # closest rating
#[1] C 
#Levels: A B C D
```

**EDIT:** for a vectorized solution

```
z <- round(runif(300, 1, 10000)) # a random volumes

# OPTION 1: sapply
z_levels1 <- sapply(z, function(x) storagerating$levels[which.min(abs(x - storagerating$volumes))])
z_levels1

# OPTION 2: for loop
z_levels2 <- vector("numeric",length(z))
for(i in 1:length(z)){
  z_levels2[i] <- storagerating$levels[which.min(abs(z[i] - storagerating$volumes))]
}
storagerating$levels[z_levels2]

# OPTION 3: make a function with sapply
lookup <- function(x, volumes){
  sapply(x, function(x) which.min(abs(x - volumes)))
}
storagerating$levels[lookup(z, storagerating$volumes)]
```

**EDIT2:** Interpolation

```
storagerating <- data.frame(volumes = seq.int(100,400,100), 
                            levels = c(1:4))
storagerating # given this
#  volumes levels
#1     100      1
#2     200      2
#3     300      3
#4     400      4

mod <- lm(levels ~ volumes, data = storagerating) # linear model example
df_new <- data.frame(volumes = z) # use our model results to estimate 
levels_new <- predict(mod, newdata = df_new) # must be data.frame with same var name
storagerating_new <- cbind(df_new, levels_new)
head(storagerating_new); tail(storagerating_new)
#  volumes levels_new
#1       1       0.01
#2       3       0.03
#3       5       0.05
#4       7       0.07
#5       9       0.09
#6      11       0.11
#    volumes levels_new
#195     389       3.89
#196     391       3.91
#197     393       3.93
#198     395       3.95
#199     397       3.97
#200     399       3.99
```

Comment: Thanks @Evan. It worked, however not as a vector. If I want z as a vector (or matrix) and a vector (or matrix) of answers, your code gives me one answer based on the last value in the vector. Can we use this code or a modified version for vector? Or I should write a loop to read each value individually?

Comment: Yes you do have to loop or apply to vectorize, see my edits above

Comment: Thanks so much @Evan. The function version is very good for a vector. I am now trying to make it applicable for a matrix of z. Thanks again.

Comment: I applied a simple loop over the function and it is working for matrix as well. Thanks again @Evan Friedland

Comment: Thanks @Evan. Just one more question: if I need to interpolate instead of closest match, what is the best approach?

Comment: Interpolate what? I interpreted the question to be converting volumes to levels. What is an example of a level and a level interpolated? For example here I am using "A" and "B" as 2 levels. Are you interpolating a new level between them? I'm just a little confused

Comment: Most of the times, the volume to be found (z in your code) is not available in the volume /level table (storage rating). Therefore your code finds the level based on the closest volume in the table. It is good if instead, it interpolates between volume and finds the interpolated levels. For your background, the volumes to be found are generated from a model and not necessarily the same as what is in the volume/level table.

Comment: Right I'm just asking for an example of an "interpolated level"?

Comment: For instance, if z=234000 and table says

volume    level
#1 230000    5
# 2 235000    10

your code answer is 10 because it is the closest match. However, another option is a linear interpolation:
((234000-230000)*(10-5)/(235000 - 230000))+ 5= 9

Comment: Just trying to understand this, your levels are numbers? That's why I am confused. levels typically is interpreted as "factors" or ranks. They are categorical variables and you can't interpolate between them. But if z_volume is a level of 3... is your level just a scaling down of units? Can you have decimals?

Comment: Both volumes and levels are numbers. Volumes are the volume of water in the reservoir (megalitres) and levels are the level of water in the reservoir (metre). Levels can have decimals as well 9.2, 9.8, etc.

Comment: Please see my edits and let me know if this helps you, my example is a perfect fit, yours likely will not be. Without specifics it's hard for me to give you something more detailed.

Answer (score 3):

The word level has caused some confusion. Level refers to a physical measurement water level (depth). Each water level relates to a specific volume, e.g.:

level volume
0       0
1       30
2       35
3       37
4       38

These relationships are typically not linear and slightly random jumps because of the geometry of the reservoir. The question is how to find the volume when the measured level is 3.5 (which in this case would be 37.5. The approx function can do linear interpolation.

My solution:

```
cap <- data.frame(level = 0:4, volume = c(0, 20, 33, 35, 36))
res <- data.frame(level = c(0.5, 1.2, 2.7, 3.2))
vol <- lapply(res, function(l) approx(cap$level, cap$volume, xout=l))
vol <- vol$level
plot(cap$level, cap$volume, type="b")
points(vol$x, vol$y, col="red", pch = 19)
```

P.S. @Heerj is that Heerbod?

Comment: Although the accepted answer is nice and complete, I believe that @Peter better addresses the real problem (not well formulated, I agree). I have found his solution elegant and useful. Just a note for new readers: the accepted solution relies on a linear model of the full dataset, which might not be true in all cases.